# SAPHANA JDBC example URL for liquibase update

Tags: java, jdbc, liquibase, hana

I was trying to run a liquibase update on a SAPHANA trial Db after connecting through a tunnel.I am not able to get the right JDBC connection url. 
The JDBC url show in the CMD of tunnel opener is as below:-
jdbc:sap://localhost:30015/?currentschema=NEO_BRIIDEQ3NHN31DYZMKHISXHZM

where as URL for oracle works seamlessly.
Please help me out with the same.
Thanks

Comment: This is not a liquibase problem but rather a network problem (or mabye a JDBC problem).

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference: There is an SAP Hana extension for liquibase available [here](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Hana+extension) that might add some support to liquibase for SAPs Hana DB.

Answer (score 0):

SAPHANA does not appear to be a supported Liquibase database.